How to predict the time for hydride formation after knowing the initial and final concentration of hydrogen into hydride?
I was trying to do time based calculations in terms of predicting the amount of time it will take to form the first hydride ($\ce{LaNi5H6}$) once the hydrogen is pass through the metal($\ce{LaNi5}$), the first hydride formation will be at the start of the PCT plateau curve, while I know the concentration at that point with the pressures and temperatures at that point along with the highest hydrogen concentration in the curve. Also, in the PCT curve, I know the properties for the metal/alloy/IMC and would like to know the formula to predict the time it will take from the lowest concentration to the point where hydride($\beta$) phase formation occurs. Can I assume first order kinetics or not if nor what equations can I used and assumptions if any?

What its the meaning of the "initial and final concentration of the hydrogen into hydride" ?

I mean, the amount of hydrogen in grams in hydride at the lowest and highest concentration in metal hydride.

What formula can I use, can I estimate the time using the first order kinetics equation?
